# Decode invalid parsed string like "u0627u0644u0649 u0627u0644u0623" (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, string, unicode

I've discovered some data that includes lines like `"u0627u0644u0649 u0627u0644u0623"`. Normally, these would be more like `\u0627\u0644\u0649 \u0627\u0644\u0623` but something's gone wrong with the data. In order to correct it my only option is to adjust what's there.

I haven't found any instances where strings were a combination of both `"u0627u0644u0623 u0644 u0627"` and "*normal words*" but this could occur.

I also want to convert anything like `"\u0627\u0644"` or a combination thereof, safely, so that a string like "My string `\u0627\u0644 u0627u0644u0623 u0644 u0627."` would be converted correctly.

Could anyone recommend a regex or appropriate method to safely "fix" these strings?

**UPDATE**

What if we only corrected strings where we first tested to ensure it only contains strings like `u0627u0644u0649 u0627u0644u0623`? Could that be done safely (and how)?

Now, I am using

```
^(u[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}\s?)+$
```

My regex works well enough for the purposes needed. I also agree there's likely no guaranteed solution but this seems to work in my test cases thus far.

Comment: If regular text gets glued with these corrupt hex codes, you can't have a 100% safe solution.

Comment: What if we only corrected strings where we first tested to ensure it only contains strings like "u0627u0644u0649 u0627u0644u0623"? Could that be done safely (and how)? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, `^(?:\W*u[A-Fa-f0-9]{4})\W*$`

Comment: Thanks. I tested it, it only returns true for preg_match for a string like "u0f40" and not strings like "u0f40 u0f40" or "u0f40u0f40 u0f40", and also it returns true for a string like "\u0f40" which it shouldn't.

Comment: I believe this works - can you confirm? `^(u[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}\s?)+$`

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no regex which guarantees converting these corrupt unicode-strings to escaped form, because `"u0627u0644u0649 u0627u0644u0623"` may be used in other contexts.

Comment: What constitutes a normal word?

Comment: Normal by dictionary standards I suppose. It's ok - thank you, I had found the solution. My regex works well enough for the purposes needed. I also agree there's likely no guaranteed solution but this seems to work in my test cases thus far. Will update as I find more errors - thanks for your help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^(u[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}\s?)+$` pattern won't find matches with leading whitespace.

To only match strings that contain `u[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}` and whitespace (`\s`) patterns, you may use

```
'~^\s*u[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}(?:\s*u[A-Fa-f0-9]{4})*\s*$~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VvW9bR/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `u[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}` - `u` and then four hex chars
- `(?:\s*u[A-Fa-f0-9]{4})*` - 0 or more occurrences of sequences of

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `u[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}` - `u` and then four hex chars
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

You may shorten it to  `'~^\s*(u[A-Fa-f0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?1))*\s*$~'` in PHP.